# How can this boolean algebra equation be solved?

Tags: boolean-algebra

```
(7EFEFEFF + A) ^ (A ^ FFFFFFFF) = 81010100
```

How can it be solved for the value A? where

- '+' means plus
- '^' is bitwise XOR

EDIT: Forgot to mention.  A is a hexadecimal variable

Comment: Is $A$ a variable or hex $10$?

Comment: A is a hexadecimal variable, 4 bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the first number ends in $FF$ and not $EF$? I am not sure there is an answer as you have written. I will change it to $EF$ and proceed.

I will give you partial answer and let you work out the rest!

$A\hbox{^}FFFF....$ is bit-wise complement of $A$ which is often denoted as $\hbox{~}A$

Note that the last two nibbles of (something ^ ~A) is $00$. So if we look at the last two nibbles of $A$ and call it $B$ then looking at last two nibbles
$$
EF + B = ~B$$
So $B$ should end in $8$ and by the same logic, nibble before the last should be 0 or 8
So $A$ ends in $08$ or $88$.

Working along the same lines we get $A=00000008$ and here are the rest of the calculations:
$$
\begin{align}
A &=00000008\\
7EFEFEEF +A  &=7EFEFEF7\\
A \hbox{^} FFFFFFFF &= FFFFFFF7\\
(7EFEFEEF +A )\hbox{^}(A\hbox^FFFFFFFF) &=81010100
\end{align}
$$